# Jquery error with angular

Tags: jquery, angular, caching, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

i ve create a project with angular and ive used some modals with jquery 
but this didn't work as i want it to work 
when i click for the first modal in the first component it work fine 
but when i move for the an other component and call an other modal , it show me the old and the new one same time

More details :

first modal into first component

[image: First image]

and when i go for another component and call an other modal[image]

i ll be so grateful if any one can help !!

first modal :

```
    <div class="ui modal nouveaux">
        <i class="close icon"></i>
        <div class="header">
            Affecter Nouveaux stage
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <form class="ui form">
            <div class="two fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Nom De Stage</label>
                    <input id="nom" type="text" placeholder="Nom de stage ..." [(ngModel)]="nomStage"
                           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Nom & prenom etudiant</label>
                    <select id="etudiant"  class="ui search dropdown" (click)="selectedhandler($event)">
                        <option disabled selected hidden>Choisir...</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let etudiant of listEtudiant" value="{{etudiant.cin}}">
                            {{etudiant.nom | titlecase}}
                            {{etudiant.prenom | titlecase}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two fields">

                <div class="field">
                    <label>Nom & prenom enseignant </label>
                    <select id="enseignant" class="ui search dropdown" (click)="selectedhandlerEnseignant($event)">
                        <option disabled selected hidden value="choisir">Choisir...</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let enseignant of listEnseignant" value="{{enseignant.id_en}}">
                            {{enseignant.nom_en | titlecase}}
                            {{enseignant.prenom_en | titlecase}}
                        </option>
                    </select>

                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Service</label>
                    <select id="service" class="ui search dropdown" (click)="selectedhandlerService($event)">
                        <option disabled selected hidden>Choisir...</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let service of listService" [value]="service.id_service">
                            {{service.nom_service | titlecase}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Date debut</label>
                    <input id="date_d" type="date" name="last-name" [(ngModel)]="date_d"
                           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Date fin</label>
                    <input id="date_f" type="date" name="last-name" [(ngModel)]="date_f"
                           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="two fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Objectif</label>
                    <select name="skills[]" class="ui fluid multiple selection dropdown" id="multi-select">
                        <option selected hidden>Choisir...</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let objectif of listObjectif" [value]="objectif.id_obj">{{objectif.des_obj | titlecase}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="nomStage?.length===0" id="span">
                <span class="ui red message">Nom de stage bligatoire</span>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="etudiantcin?.toString().length===0" id="span">
                <span class="ui red message">Etudiant bligatoire</span>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="enseignantid?.toString().length===0" id="span">
                <span class="ui red message">Enseignant bligatoire</span>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="serviceid?.toString().length===0" id="span">
                <span class="ui red message">Service bligatoire</span>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="date_d?.length===0" id="span">
                <span class="ui red message">Date debut bligatoire</span>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="date_f?.length===0" id="span">
                <span class="ui red message">Date fin bligatoire</span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui black deny button" (click)="Annuler()">
                Annuler
            </div>

            <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button" (click)="insertStage(nomStage,date_d,date_f)"
                 *ngIf="date_f && date_d && selectedObjectif && serviceid && enseignantid && etudiantcin && nomStage">
                <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
                Ajouter
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the code how i show first modal

```
showModal(): void {
    $('.ui.modal.nouveaux').modal('show');
    this.drop();
}
```

this is the second modal

```
<div class="ui modal nouveaux">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Ajouter nouveaux classe
    </div>

    <form class="ui form">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Nom de classe</label>
            <input type="text" name="Nom_de_class" id="Nom_de_class" placeholder="Nom de service" class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="nom_class" required minlength="2">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="nom_class?.length === 0" id="span">
        <span  class="ui red message" >Nom de classe est obligatoire</span>
        </div>
        <div class="actions" (click)="cancel()">
        <div class="ui black deny button">
            Annuler
        </div>
        <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button" *ngIf="nom_class" (click)="insertClasse(nom_class)">
            <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
            Ajouter
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is how i show second modal

```
showModal(): void {
        $('.ui.modal.nouveaux').modal('show');
    }
```

Comment: You should post the relevant source code (or rather, a [mcve] of your problem).

Comment: Add your code rather than showing ui.

Comment: i think it might be cache problem ... don't know because it don't change the page because it's SPA so it keep same data

Comment: mixing jquery with Angular is discouraged

Comment: well it's done right now and i run out of time and i need solution @Vikas

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Angular is not just 'discouraged', it's a big big NO. This won't solve your issue, I know, but your problem's cause is very likely because Angular has no idea what jQuery is doing, and jQuery has no idea what Angular is doing. Things will never work smoothly as long as you use both libraries together.

Comment: thanks for your help and your explicity and your experience that made me happy to solve my problem ( ps : i need this project tomorrow ) thanks @JeremyThille

Comment: My point is, there is no easy fix to your problem. Nobody can tell you, "Hey, here's how to do it". You mixed up two very different technologies, and the result is, it just doesn't work. My guess is that you'll have to develop some kind of dirty hack, with `setTimeout` and stuff like that, to somehow make it work. But we can't really know for sure what hack to develop and how to make this code work. Sorry.